# Hello World in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a Hello World page in angular.js.But it displays: **{{helloMessage}}** instead of **Hello World**. Could not understand, where is the problem.

The folder contains two files: angular.min.js and HelloWorld.html. I wrote following code in HelloWorld.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title> Hello World </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 ng-controller = "HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>
    <script src = "angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    function HelloWorldCtrl($scope){
        $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code may be based on older versions of angular where it would work. Now you should declare your controller differently as per the answers.

Comment: @Muhammad Raza welcome to StackOverflow. Since you've got 2 answers that solve your problem, you should accept the one that fits you best. See more [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is not set up correctly. It needs to be bound to your angular app. First you need to name the app:

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
```

Then change your script like so:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('HelloWorldCtrl',    
    function($scope) {
        $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
    }
);
```

Refer to the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Answer (score 0):

You're simply creating a function `HelloWorldCtrl`, but not assigning it to a controller. Check the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

You should do it like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('HelloWorldCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = "Hello World";
}]);
```